# Write to text file with bot command using discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

So basically, I want to be able to add a new employee for a game I play and store the points to rank up in the game. So the first command would be to create the new employee. So say Bob needed to be created. I would want to say "!addcurrentemployee bob" for it to write to the text file and default his points to 0. This is what I have but it isn't working:

```
@bot.command
async def addcurrentemployee(ctx, username=None, points=0):
    desk = "G:/Python/Diamond Security Bot/"
    with open(desk + "employees.txt", "rw+") as f:
        user = str(username)
        pointamount = str(points)
        points = 0
        f.write(f'{user}, {pointamount}')
        f.close()
```

Comment: Might I suggest using shelves to achieve this feat? Each employee would be in the shelve dictionary and could be updated as needed. https://docs.python.org/3/library/shelve.html

Answer (score 0):

Is there a specific error you're encountering? Is this decorated as a command? What's the input you're trying? Without more information or context beyond "it isn't working", it's difficult to determine what exactly the issue is that you're asking for help with.

Based on this snippet though, `points` will be an integer and you'll get a `TypeError` when you try to concatenate a string with it. This also applies to `username`, which will be `None` if one isn't specified. You should look into [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#fancier-output-formatting).

You might also consider using a context manager for the file instead, e.g.
`with open(desk + "employees1.txt", "w") as f:`

Comment: changed to with open(desk+"employees.txt", "rw+") as f: and made a user=str(username) and pointamount = str(points)

Comment: Again, you need to provide more information than "still didn't work". Blindly guessing what your issue is to help you is an inane method.